# SandCastle HTML output multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces, sandcastle

I am generating html documents using SandCastle for a project in C# that has multiple namespaces. The HTML output shows only one namespace. But if I go to Help/search.html and search for classes in other namespaces, I could find and locate them which means it has generated html for them. Is there a way I could see all namespaces together in HTML output as it is in the .chm file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using the VS2013 presentation style and this is a known issue (https://shfb.codeplex.com/workitem/35347).  The namespaces are all there you just need to expand to topmost node (the one with the help project title).  The other workaround is to add conceptual content or enable the root namespace container.  I'm looking into fixing it for the next release.